# Voxeo Prophecy- can I query call/line statuses from outside the server?

Tags: php, ivr

I just picked up someone else's IVR project, which uses a combination of Voxeo Prophecy on one server (to which I have access) for the phone call, which occasionally interfaces with an existing database on another server through URL's pointing to PHP scripts on a web server.

The current setup allows me to tell Prophecy to make a call by passing it a URL. My question is, is there any way for my web server to determine the status of those calls so that it can, for instance, tell Prophecy to make the next call on the web server's list?

The closest thing I've found so far to a status report is this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9995/com.voxeo.prism.ext/getAllMIB
```

but I don't even know if that's giving me a status report on the right product; the URL I'm using to make the calls looks like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9998/SessionControl/VoiceXML.start?params
```

If the prism mib is giving me the right info, it's not a problem for me to parse it for the callsup data, but I don't know what the relevant portion of the callsup data is.

Comment: Looks like the info I need is the Active CCXML10 sessions from 127.0.0.1:9999/sessions_10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While `myServer.com:9999/sessions_10` will work, it is not a recommended API for polling purposes, rather you will want to work off the stats_10 servlet.

For example this will return the number of ports in use:

`http://myserver.com:9999/stats_10?&type=counters&format=value&value=CT/Allocated/Ports`

http://docs.voxeo.com/prophecy/11.0/monitoringstats.htm?search=stats_10#anchor

Additionally, what is most common, is that developers will track the status of outbound calls via their back-end system through asynchronous http calls from the application, while the outbound call is in progress, connected, failed, or disconnected for example.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the info I need is the Active CCXML10 sessions from 127.0.0.1:9999/sessions_10

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend writing your own CCXML to handle the call process. There are a lot of examples in [Voxeos documentation on CCXML](http://docs.voxeo.com/ccxml/1.0-final/). Look at Section F on "Outbound Dialing". There are a lot of events you can capture this way. It also includes call progress analysis to help determine if you got an answering machine or a human.  This way you can play different messages dependent upon whether you got a live person or not, or handle the processing differently (no sense prompting a machine for a response). The other event you will get is call completion so you can tell the web server to send out the next call.  You can use the "send" tag to basically give your application a call-back indicating that it is ready for the next call.